# Nucleophilic Substitution with ethyl bromide and NaOH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> Given is following nucleophilic reaction with product A. Draw the mechanism of the reaction and give the structure formula of A.
>   [image: Nucleophilic reaction]

Here is my solution, I am sure it is not right. Could you help me, step by step to understand this reaction.
[image: Solution]

Comment: OH isn't a great nucleophile but is a good base. What is the most acidic proton in the starting material?

Comment: I think the H by OH,becauce it has a pKa from 10, and the N has a pKa bigger than 10. So the NaOH take the H and we have $O^-$

Comment: Correct! And phenoxide is a good nucleophile.

Comment: ok, so the phenoxide will replace the Br.

Comment: Exactly so. The reaction ethylates the phenol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help from Waylander (s.o.) we get the following mechanism.

[image: solution]

Comment: Looks correct to me